# Validate integer length for serial number

Tags: c, validation

I had been given homework for making an app library, and I am stuck with validation.
How do I validate integer length? For example, I am inputting the book serial number but the length serial number must be between 13-15 digit. I know how to do it with string, but I dont know how to do it with integer/number.

Below is the validation for the book name

```
if(strlen(name)>=3 && strlen(name)<=25 && validasiName(name)){
    break;
}else{
    system("cls");
}
```

and this one for the serial number

```
if(ISBN>=13 && ISBN<=16){
    break;
}else{
    system("cls");
}
```

Comment: Suggest you treat it as a string instead of an int to make your life easier. That is, read it in and store it as a string unless/until there is a reason it needs to be converted to an int.

Comment: Just read `ISBN` as a string & verify/validate ISBN (for numbers & X-checkdigit if necessary) which includes `strlen()`. [ISBN - Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number)

Comment: Book serial numbers are strings of digits, sometimes with hyphens for legibility; they are not numbers. For example, the numerals “03” and “3” would both represent the number 3, and there would be no way of telling them apart once they are read into an `int` because the `int` records only the number, not the original digits. But the strings “03” and “3” are different. Read the serial number as a string of characters, not as a number.

Answer (score 0):

When you're asking for the number of digits, you are really asking "how many times can I divide this number by 10 before it's less than 10?"

A simple recursive implementation would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int numLen(unsigned long num){
    if(num < 10) 
        return 1;
    return 1 + numLen(num/10);
}


int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", numLen(1));
    printf("%d\n", numLen(12));
    printf("%d\n", numLen(ULONG_MAX));
}
```

Just make sure you're not putting in negative numbers